# It is possible to make a button act as hyperlink or other similliar,but targetting other frame ? (HTML)

Tags: html, css, dom

So as mentioned on the title,it is possible ? i've tried few ways,but nothing work.The last code i try make the text on the button have undrline on it,so what i'm trying to do is *as mentioned on the title* + without make the text inside the button have underline.

And thankyou before

**Edit** : Since it look like not clear enough so,here's the case
i've three HTML page
let say *index.html*,*list.html*,and *judul.html*

-The HTML code of *list.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="new 2.html" target="tengah">
        <input type="submit" value="About Us">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

-Then *index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frame</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%" bordercolor='blue' noresize id="judul">
    <frame src="Judul.html" id="atas">
    <frameset cols="15%,85%" id="kolom">
        <frame src="list.html" id="daftar">
        <frame src="" id="tengah">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

And the last one *judul.html* is not included since it set the other element like how big the row or what content should displayed according to the condiditon.
so what i'm exactly trying to do is **Make a button on list.html that link to other page but show it to a frame with ID tengah** so it is possible ?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you exactly want and what have you tried that didnt work like the codes etc?

Comment: Well this is the other code that closest to what i try to do
`<form action="http://google.com">
   <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
  </form>`
but what i'm exactly want is make the link open in other frame of the main page. i also have put an "id" on the frame,what i don't know is targetting it from button

Comment: You should add the clarifications to the question itself, so that the question is understandable as such, without reading all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

With the JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    frame.src = 'http://url.com/';

});
```

Comment: I've do that but it's ended with open it in other tab instead the taegetted frame.
`<form action="new 2.html" target="tengah">
   <input type="submit" value="About Us">
  </form>`
and,is space allowed on _action_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target` attribute in the `form` element:

```
<form action="..." target="...">
<input type="submit" value="...">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this with JQuery:

```
$('#btn').bind("click", function() {
    $('#frame').attr('src',"http://someurl.com");
    return false;
});
```

to remove underlined text use this css:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: jQuery wasn't tagged.

Comment: So what? JQuery is also javascript dummy!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't feel like a dummy for avoiding 90kb of dependencies to do something this straightforward.

Comment: Yep, 90kb is huge file in year 2013 using DSL connection or any phone data connection. And that one command is usually all you need in your site JS.. :)

Comment: @Hardy So if use this JQuery,how the full code will be ? sorry i'm very very new to HTML and it's stuff